# Is it Possible to use Visual Studio/C# to develop for SharePoint 2007 without Deploying DLL to Hive

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

If a customer does not allow installation of a .dll into their SharePoint 2007 hive (or the GAC), is there any way to create webparts, etc. with Visual Studio that will not require deployment of the .dll(s) into the hive (or the GAC)?  If not, is there another way to use Visual Studio and/or C# with the SharePoint namespace functionality in a similar fashion even if not quite in the standard way? This customer isn't going to allow us to install anything on the box beyond the pages and, if not into the GAC or hive, SharePoint-related .dlls developed by us.

Note: there are some specific project details at the end of the post.

---

Final Summary of Accepted Answer:

- No answer was forthcoming with an alternative method of deploying custom SharePoint assemblies (e.g. not GAC and not hive).
- It is possible, however, to use C# embedded in a page, and you may reference the SharePoint assembly and use it in the code. (see accepted answer for details)
- Many of the things that I had expected would need custom code do not seem to, nor does it seem that in many cases it would even be possible/beneficial to do so.

---

I have a few basic ideas on how it might work ("magic happens"), but, being firmly in the "don't know what I don't know" quadrant right now, I don't know if it can be done, and I don't know whether any possible alternative route would even gain anything beyond just developing directly in SharePoint Designer sans C#/Visual Studio altogether.

ideas:

- Develop with Visual Studio as normal, using WSPBuilder or a stock SharePoint project, but instead of normal deployment, installing the .dll(s) in a non-hive location on the machine, and then somehow including the items as an external resource.
- Create a self-hosting web service that somehow can be called serve up components that can be incorporated into the SharePoint site.
- Develop separate web pages/web controls in a non-SharePoint web project, then including them somehow into the SharePoint site; or, somehow creating a reference to them in the IIS directories
- Develop seperate web pages/web controls in a WebApplication and using the Hostable WebCore to deliver what is needed, and, of course, somehow including the served up pages into SharePoint.

And, my final concern is that even should I figure out the details on the "magic happens" steps, I still would really not have gotten what I want, which is to be able to use the functionality of the SharePoint namespace in a useful way, e.g. connected to the site we are developing, and with sufficient access to do what we need without jumping through too many hoops, either from a developer perspective (e.g. code that's hard to use or maintain), or a bad user experience (e.g. user repeatedly getting login prompts).

(My apologies if the answer is obvious; I'm brand new to SharePoint development, and I'm only experienced with high-level Web development (e.g. fairly simple .ascx/.aspx, and mostly using the designer for pages), so I'm having to get my bearings quickly. When I search for help with the 'obvious' search terms, I get an overwhelming amount of information for normal scenarios, but have not found an answer for this.)

---

Upon request, here are the details that I can give about the particular project. I currently have information on only a piece of it, and it's a long-term project with a lot of pieces that will build on one another.  So, unfortunately, if the solution isn't fairly generic, I will probably have to go the SharePoint Designer route to avoid the risk associated with relying on a method which may not be compatible with pieces that come down the road. Also, I apologize for how generic these are; I am trying to provide a list of capabilities needed as opposed to detailing the actual project.

- ability to have individual user site home-pages that allow them to view various bits of information about projects they own and projects they are involved in
- ability to have site templates that store wizard-type steps to be followed by users
- ability to link the wizard templates to various documents and possibly other things associated with the various steps
- ability to store various associated roles and attributes (such as how much time is allowed for a task to be completed) with the items in the templates
- ability for a user to use the wizard to create instances of the site items and allow or enforce the assignment of other users based on the template attributes
- ability for some roles associated with an item to edit the document and save it back, and to restrict others from editing them
- ability for users other than the creator of the project (probably based on a project role assigned by the user) to view all info (timelines, etc.) and edit all documents in the project
- ability for the associated users that have roles assigned to mark off when they are complete with their portion of the task
- ability to calculate timelines based on info from the attributes for the different items in the project
- ability to notify users (via email and site homepage notifications) in roles that have to take action or are marked as needing to received updates on one or more project items
- ability to lock down project items from modification once a step has been completed; and possibly to unlock and/or retract steps
- ability to automatically create reports and send them to appropriate locations (probably e-mail, but also possibly an administration page on the site, or to another site entirely.)
- ability to mark completed projects and archive them in a separate section only viewable by certain windows groups or groups defined on-site

I also know that there is an intent to greatly increase the scope of this project once we complete the first part to the customer's customer's satisfaction.  I am trying to find out more information and will post here if/when that is available.

I realize that some of what's there might really have nothing to do with SharePoint in particular, and some of it may not really give enough information to tell you which feature or other it will need.  I am happy to clarify anything that doesn't make sense, but I wanted to try to give a little detail as someone else may have a lot better idea of what SharePoint pieces would be necessary or possible to use than I.

Comment: I'm going to assume that if the client won't allow hive deployment they'll nix the GAC as well, but that's one option if somehow they'll allow.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. We found out we were not allowed to install a .dll to the hive by providing them a sample project for them to try, but even before we created the sample we were told not to use the GAC. Thank you for mentioning it, I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can at all wing it, you should see if it would be possible for an upgrade from sharepoint 2007 to 2010 to be made, because many of the problems you are describing are made a whole lot easier to solve in 2010.

Something that would really help me develop a more thorough answer is a very brief description of what functionality you are attempting to achieve.

---

OK, Thanks for the update.
I will try my best to address all the points of the project.

- Your first point is easily available using something called a [Mysite](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-my-site-HA010108748.aspx).
- For all the points where you are discussing wizard templates that can store documents and associated data, you might want to look into [Microsoft Infopath](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath/), no guarantee that it'll be a perfect match, but take a look and decide.
- The great part about infopath is that when you combine it with Sharepoint Workflows, you can set rules for doing things, and different views, this will allow you to assign roles associated with editing privileges and such on documents.
- Again, since infopath has the ability to easily submit to a sharepoint list or document library, any data based calculations are as easy as selecting which data you want, and what you want to do with it.
- For the notifications, sharepoint workflows in microsoft sharepoint designer allow easy email creation.
- As far as your last bullet point goes, this is another workflow, and the ability to make sites viewable to only certain groups is a basic functionality of sharepoint.

These are all available in SP 2007, but honestly, it would be financially more responsible as far as the difficulty and length of the project to use SP 2010. Also, the transition process is smooth and you don't really lose anything, just gain. From what you've said though, this might not be possible, which is a shame, but good luck either way!

---

This part should help you out with the C# pages, here is a basic hello world page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
  public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Response.Write("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
  }
</script>
```

I normally code this in sharepoint designer. Also, say if you need to work with `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`, provided on the server, you could add this line: `<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Sharepoint" %>`, since it is a page on the server, you don't need to specifically link it in any way, just that one little line after the page language declaration. Hope this clears everything up!

Comment: As for moving to SharePoint 2010, when I first got pulled onto the project, I did some comparisons between versions and asked this question. Unfortunately the answer wasn't even "no" it was more like "not a chance". :)

As for a description of the functionality I need to achieve: the problem is that it's a long-term project and I have a very small amount of information about just one of the pieces. So, if it's not a fairly generic solution, I likely will avoid it as basic risk-aversion.

Comment: That said, if you could give me some hints as to what categories of things you think it might be possible to do this for, I can probably talk to the PM and narrow things down somewhat as to what the scope is. I would try to describe for you better but, again, I'm new enough to SharePoint that I am very fuzzy on what a good breakdown would be other than just telling you the entire project, and I know that I'm not at liberty to do that. :)  Heck they won't even let us install a .dll. :D

Comment: I sent an e-mail asking whether they could give me more information on the later phases of the project; if I can figure out a good way to sum it up I will let you know. I also am about to edit the question to at least provide generic information about the part I do know about right now, hopefully it will be somewhat useful in giving some scope.  Oh, and thank you for your answer! Sorry, got too wrapped up in my responses and didn't say earlier. :)

Comment: Wow this is great, thank you. I'm looking into it all now. Again, as for 2010 vs. 2007 I totally agree, and in fact I think not being allowed to use all the development tools has the same points to be made. However, it was made clear to me that the end customer is not going to be flexible on either issue. (Although, strangely, the possibility of further work migrating to 2010 *after* the project has been completed has been mentioned. *sigh*)

Comment: I do notice that none of your points seem to address using the Visual Studio development tools while under the restrictions we have. (e.g. no .dll deployment to GAC or hive.) Is your opinion that it's not possible, or not worth it, or something else? Assuming we didn't have the restrictions at all, is there a significant advantage to using the Visual Studio/C# development abilities? My assumption all along was that the dev tools would have simplified things somewhat, so perhaps I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to put that in there. The thing is, as far as that goes, I don't completely understand. We have done things that are very extensive in sharepoint. Custom coded events, ASP.NET w/ C#, uploading documents, reading lists, running scripts, etc. This being said, I have no clue what you are saying for .dll deployment. We have never needed to deploy .dlls, I don't understand why you need to.

Comment: Oh, hmm. Well, I was told I should create a sample WebPart using Visual Studio, which I did, then built a .wsp using WSPBuilder.  This, however, created an assembly .dll with our custom WebPart class in it as part of the .wsp, which would then, in turn, be installed into their hive.  On our server it worked fine, but on their end they wouldn't allow it because of the .dll. So, I was looking for an alternative. How do you go about using C# without having an assembly with the code in it, that was actually one of the things I was hoping might be a possibility if the alternate install wasn't.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, we never had to use custom web parts. The way you would do what you're looking to do would be to make a .aspx page. I'll update my post.

Comment: Oh that's terrific, thanks for posting how to do that! I don't know that it clears everything up :D, but that does answer the question in that it shows how I can at least use C# including using the SharePoint.dll, and it doesn't even require any sort of hack! And, the rest of the information you gave is a terrific start on everything.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to deploy code to the BIN directory instead of the GAC.

The [BIN directory runs with minimal trust](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/02837576-c667-48e2-b3aa-3ad3a73078f9/). However, some things can't be deployed here (like event receivers).

See also, [How to deploy a SharePoint web part to bin](http://simplesharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-deploy-sharepoint-web-part-to.html).

Comment: awesome, thank you, we talked to a consultant today at work and he suggested this as a possibility, but it sounded like it might be hard to get all the configuration handled correctly. we're waiting for some more information on what is required to set it up and whether it really will end up having what we need since it's partial trust. :) very much appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

[We](http://www.navertica.com) have a solution which employs IronPython scripts. There's a IronPython web console, generic IronPython event receiver, page, workflow, timerjob, library of scripts which can also be edited through web interface, and a list with necessary configurations. I'm hoping to opensource the core of it at some point, but the full version can do a lot more.

The point is we don't need to do redeploys for every single little thing that needs to be added or changed for each particular customer. Particularly with workflows - we can do small changes without breaking everything that's currently running.

Comment: what has to be installed on the target machine though?

Comment: It's one .wsp solution - so it does need deployment to GAC, and it cannot run sandboxed. However, it allows you to develop quite a lot of stuff without even needing Visual Studio or deploying anything else.

When I look at the requirements, most of the second half should be easily possible.

Comment: But the .wsp has at least one .dll for IronPython I assume? As stated in the updated question, installing any .dll to their GAC will not be allowed. Thanks for trying to help me get this figured out, though. :)